# sql server query not giving output in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
string query = @"select p.package_id, pd.download_id
                     from Tools.ftp.package p
                     join Tools.ftp.package_download pd 
                     on p.package_id = pd.package_id
                     where p.package_name = 'foo'";
```

Trying to pull data from sql server in C# with SqlConnection class, I get output without the where statement but a blank file with it left in, also odd behavior with more complicated joins.  Why is that.  Is there anything to watch for behavior wise when writing queries in C#, ie formatting issues and whatnot.

Here's the whole thing.

```
StreamWriter fileout = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test\output9.csv");

    string myConnectionString = @"Data Source=foobar;Initial Catalog=DB;User id=user;Password=pw";
    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);


    string query = @"select p.package_id, pd.download_id
                 from Tools.ftp.package p
                 join Tools.ftp.package_download pd 
                 on p.package_id = pd.package_id
                 where p.package_name = 'foo'";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Conn);
    cmd.Connection = Conn;
    Conn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    da.Fill(dt);
    Conn.Close();
    da.Dispose();


    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
    {
        foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
        {
            fileout.Write(item+ ",");
        }
        fileout.Write("\n");
    }
    fileout.Close();
```

Comment: Tried running that SQL in management studio and see what results you get out? Any rows returned? I am imagine you are using SqlDataReader or a DataTable too right?

Comment: You need to provide more than just the dynamic sql also I would recommend putting that query into a stored procedure or if you are not familiar with how to do that.. re-factor that query into Parameterized query.. you need to show the code in which you are declaring the SQLCommand as well as how you are `Executing` the query

Comment: I think you are missing 'as' keyword. Here -> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: What makes you think he is missing the `AS` keyword.. it doesn't appear that he is using `Aliasing` so Colin I may have to disagree with you on that one

Comment: if the =`foo1 does not return data have you tried using the `Like` Keyword  `where p.package_name Like 'foo%'";`

Comment: @ColinSteel `AS` is optional - he renames them to `p` and `pd`

Comment: when you debug have you tried hovering over `dt` in this line hitting the little magnifying glass and seeing if the DataTable displays any rows `da.Fill(dt);`

Comment: it can't be like, I need exactly foo.  as keyword doesn't have anything to do with I don't think.

Comment: also how and where is `fileout` defined.. please show all relevant code

Comment: yea I did use the data visualizer from the debugger, with the where clause it becomes a blank table.  what is going on

Comment: the other wierd thing is I can take out the join clause and keep the where clause in and it gives me output.

Answer (score 2):

> I can take out the join clause and keep the where clause in and it gives me output

That means there are no matching records in `Tools.ftp.package_download`  Try a left join instead:

```
select p.package_id, pd.download_id
     from Tools.ftp.package p
     LEFT join Tools.ftp.package_download pd 
     on p.package_id = pd.package_id
     where p.package_name = 'foo'
```

Comment: I just realized that even when it's returning output, it's different from the output given by management studio, so when I added the where clause it's conceivable there are no longer any matches, so my unfiltered data is incorrect to begin with, but why would the same statement return different results.  I checked the db name and schema and made sure I'm in the same environment

Comment: I don't think you quite understand how joins work might be worth looking at http://www.1keydata.com/sql/inner-join.html.

Comment: It has nothing to do with joins.  I changed the environment in management studio and restarted vs 2008 and it worked, just one of those things..